# When is partial autocorrelation is important, but not the full autocorrelation?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am modelling changes in diversity (using a modified Shannon-Weiner index over time for several sites) with a GAM.

When I look at the acf and pacf plots, I don't see much autocorrelation in the acf plot, but there does seem to be a stronger indication for autocorrelation in pacf plot (plots below are from using the full dataset). Should I be addressing this in my model?

[image]
[image]

If so, I need to address the autocorrelation, what is the best approach?  I've attempted the following below, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.  I've only included a subset of my dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                              "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                              "C", "C", "C", "C", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                              "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                              "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                              "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                              "M", "M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
                              "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), 
                     year = c(1985, 1986, 1987, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
                              1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
                              2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 1970, 
                              1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 
                              1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
                              1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
                              1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
                              2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
                              1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
                              2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2014, 2015), 
                     D = c(1.14, 1.45, 1.32, 1.32, 1.75, 2.68, 2.59, 2.42, 2.35, 2.26, 
                           2.19, 1.46, 1.85, 1.99, 2.33, 2.1, 2.04, 1.42, 1.96, 1.27, 
                           1.72, 1.59, 1.55, 1.47, 1.41, 1.41, 2.23, 2.43, 2.35, 2.12, 
                           1.95, 2.31, 2.38, 2.01, 2.51, 2.71, 2.34, 1.93, 2.85, 2.9, 
                           2.47, 2.27, 3.08, 2.79, 2.76, 2.13, 2.71, 2.24, 2.57, 3.47, 
                           2.97, 3.55, 3.25, 3.72, 3.15, 3.41, 2.55, 2.98, 3.01, 3.02, 
                           3.77, 2.48, 2.88, 3.42, 3.07, 2.62, 2.24, 3.69, 3.59, 2.29, 
                           2.85, 2.72, 1.92, 2.98, 1.77, 1.9, 2.34, 1.68, 2.16, 2.18, 
                           1.78, 1.86, 1.48, 2.14, 2.06, 1.68, 1.67)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -87L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) %>% 
  mutate(site = factor(site))

m <- gam(D ~ s(year, by = site) + s(site, bs = "re"), 
         data = df, 
         correlation = corAR1(form = ~ year | site))

acf(m$residuals)
pacf(m$residuals)
```

Comment: 1. You need to make the (p)acf-plots by site. 2. Usually the partical autocorrelation is what you should look at. 3. I don't see a strong autocorrelation in either of the plots. 4. I suggest you fit the model without correlation structure and compare the models' AIC.

Comment: That model isn't using the `correlation` argument - that argument *only* works in `gamm()` *note the extra m*. Were you to fit the model so that it actually includes the AR(1), then you should use the `resid()` extractor on the `$lme` component of the fitted model and use `resid(m$lme, type = "normalized")` to get normalized residuals, which take account of the correlation structure. You can fit the model you want with `bam()` if you are willing to specify the $\rho$ parameter for the AR part. See `?bam` for how to specify the model.

Comment: If you plot ACF and PACF on the same scale, you will discover that the PACs are not really more pronounced than ACs.